# Issue in binding Image Source with two different file format

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagesource

My application takes .tiff and .png images, when I upload `.tiff` image `image.Source.Height` and `image.Source.Width` is set to smaller values than actual dimensions of uploaded .tiff image. But when I upload `.png` image `image.Source.Height` and `image.Source.Width` is set to actual image values. Why is this happening?

Comment: May have to do with the tiff's DPI values. Are the values of PixelWidth and PixelHeight what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageSource Width and Height are different from PixelWidth and PixelHeight.
DPI change the Width and Height.

Note : If you want to resize a BitmapSource :

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapImageFromBitmapSourceResized(BitmapSource bitmapSource, int newWidth)
    {
        BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);

        bImg.BeginInit();
        bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
        bImg.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
        bImg.EndInit();
        memoryStream.Close();
        return bImg;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
Image.Source.PixelWidth
```

to have the exact width in pixel.

Indeed the Width parameter depends on the dpi value of the image, whereas pixelwidth don't.